# CAN (Controller Area Network) on Android

Tags: android, can-bus, communication-protocol

I am trying to connect control multiple device on the network centrally via a tablet/android device and have some issues trying to find the right protocol for secure communication.

Is there a api available for coding/utilizing CAN network on android over Ethernet/Bluetooth/Wifi ? Or is there another protocol that is more suitable for my application?

Thank you.

Comment: Can your "devices" understand CAN? Ignoring CAN, Can they support Wireless communication? Answers of these two questions might help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are able to use will be determined by what protocol your devices support.

However, the use of a [CAN bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) is meant primarily to reduce wiring between the components, so implementing it over a wireless protocol is pretty much nonsense.

Considering you have the alternatives you mentioned (Ethernet/Bluetooth/Wifi), assuming some kind of TCP/IP network between your devices **HTTPS** would be a reasonable protocol to use.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use a [CAN bus to Android](http://www.gwentechembedded.com/?product=gt1026-android-can-bus-usb-adapter) dongle specifically designed for this application.  It uses Google's USB open accessory to communicate through USB.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a PC with CAN adapter, you can use https://github.com/dschanoeh/socketcand daemon and an app (you'll have to write it yourself using available Java classes from https://github.com/dschanoeh/Kayak) on your tablet to directly communicate with CAN nodes.

Another way is to use some Ethernet/Wifi gateway like [NetCAN Plus 110 Mini](http://www.visionsystems.de/produkte/netcan-plus-110-mini.html) or [NetCAN Plus 120 WLAN](http://www.visionsystems.de/produkte/netcan-plus-110-netcan-plus-120-wlan.html). You'll need to write an Android app opening a TCP channel and talking ASCII protocol to these gateways.

For Bluetooth http://www.rmcan.com/index.php?id=1067